# JQuery detect widget attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web application with a medium amount of ajax requests.

I load all jquery and jquery widgets on head then i load my base.js before close body tag.

```
function baseScripts() {
        $(".open-dialog").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();        
            alert("Opening dialog");        
            href = $().buildUrl($(this).attr("href"), "&isAjax=true");        
            $().createDialog(href, "Window Title");        
            return false;
        });

        $("input:hidden.select").each(function () {
                var element = $(this);            
                if (!($("#s2id_" + element.attr("id")).length)) {
                    $(element).select2({
                        // select2 properties...
                    });
                }
            });
        }
}
```

**SCRIPT BLOCK TO LOAD BASE SCRIPTS ON EVERY AJAX REQUEST**

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(baseScripts);
```

The problem is after every ajax request the base scripts its called again and them opening dialog multiple times and attaching select2 multiples times too.

**How i can detect if widget is already attached into element or class?
Execute scripts on every ajax request (like i did) its a bad pratice?**

Comment: Set a flag or a data attribute

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense that you will want to re-bind the click event and select2 on `ajaxComplete`. They should be a one-time binding, in which case, you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    baseScripts();

    function baseScripts() {
        $(".open-dialog").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            alert("Opening dialog");

            href = $().buildUrl($(this).attr("href"), "&isAjax=true");

            $().createDialog(href, "Window Title");

            return false;
        });

        $("input:hidden.select").each(function () {
            var element = $(this);

            if (!($("#s2id_" + element.attr("id")).length)) {
                $(element).select2({
                    // select2 properties...
                });
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Every ajax request doesn't have access from previous included scripts even on head or before body closes.

So do i load again or on every ajax request call all scripts again.

Comment: Making an ajax request doesn't reload your page. So if you called `baseScripts()` before making the ajax call (as I mentioned), your `open-dialog`'s `click` event-binding, and `select2` instantiation should remain intact after your ajax call.

Comment: Yes they will! The problem is if already have bind attached the dialog open twice!

Comment: @Trxplz0 Sounds like the problem is elsewhere in your codes. Can you update your post with your complete js codes? I think you omitted some details. If they are a lot, you can email them to me at ihcsim at gmail.

Comment: I'm including all scripts (jquery, jquery ui, select2) on html head, then i have only this block of code before html body closes. When i do a ajax request they can acess jquery or select2 (plugin) unless i include jquery again or call this baseScripts on every ajaxComplete wich is binding click event twice... so when i click in button with .open-dialog class open multiple dialogs.

Comment: @Trxplz0 I'm still unsure how you end up with multiple dialogs on-click, without looking at the rest of your codes. I have edited my answer with your codes included. Try that, and remove any ajax calls you got to see if that works.

Comment: I can send you the full code but is the same thing you have posted. I don't understand why the html code from ajax request can't have reference to included scripts. I do not wan't bind "CLICK EVENT" again but i need because it's not working without then!